# system of ODEs with two dependent functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> > $\phi_{x}=\dot\imath\frac{a}{2b}\phi-\frac{1}{b}e^{-\dot\imath(x+\frac{a}{2}t)}\chi$,
> >     $\phi_{t}=\dot\imath\frac{b}{4}\phi+\frac{\dot\imath}{2}e^{-\dot\imath(x+\frac{a}{2}t)}\chi$
> >
> > $\chi_{x}=-\dot\imath\frac{a}{2b}\chi+\frac{1}{b}e^{\dot\imath(x+\frac{a}{2}t)}\phi$,
> >     $\chi_{t}=\frac{\dot\imath}{2}e^{\dot\imath(x+\frac{a}{2}t)}\phi-\frac{\dot\imath b}{4}\chi$
> >
> > where $a$ and $b$ are constants. How one can find the solution for $\phi$ and $\chi$ by solving the above mentioned system of ODEs?

Comment: Is there no mathematician who can solve these equations?